# Why does Riak log "inavailable channel closed" message to ERROR

Tags: java, riak

I'm not a Riak expert, but it seems like the `inavailable channel closed` message should be an INFO level, not an ERROR level log message. We're opening some Riak connections when our server boots up to fetch user data, and then they time out (which should be okay, right?), when they time out the `inavailable channel closed` messages display.

Are we using Riak wrong? Is there a REAL error? Or should this just be an INFO level because it's part of the normal Riak lifecycle?

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.basho.riak/riak-client/2.0.0/com/basho/riak/client/core/RiakNode.java

```
13:13:51.533 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG s.r.s.i.n.u.i.JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator - Generated: scifinder.riak.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakMessageMatcher
13:13:51.541 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG s.r.s.i.n.u.i.JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator - Generated: scifinder.riak.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.com.basho.riak.client.core.FutureOperationMatcher
13:13:51.552 [main] INFO  com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - RiakNode started; riak.address.org:8087
13:13:51.553 [main] INFO  c.basho.riak.client.core.RiakCluster - RiakCluster is starting.
13:13:51.865 [main] INFO  com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - RiakNode started; riak.address.org:8087
13:13:51.865 [main] INFO  c.basho.riak.client.core.RiakCluster - RiakCluster is starting.
13:13:52.174 [main] INFO  com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - RiakNode started; riak.address.org:8087
13:13:52.174 [main] INFO  c.basho.riak.client.core.RiakCluster - RiakCluster is starting.
13:13:52.206 [main] DEBUG com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - Operation being executed on RiakNode riak.address.org:8087
13:13:52.220 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG s.r.s.i.n.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dscifinder.riak.shaded.io.netty.leakDetectionLevel: simple
13:13:52.233 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - Operation onSuccess() channel: id:-486690393 riak.address.org:8087
13:13:52.234 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG c.basho.riak.client.core.RiakCluster - operation complete; remaining retries: 2
13:13:52.235 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - Channel id:-486690393 returned to pool
13:13:52.235 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - Released pool permit
```

Error Logs

```
14:13:31.708 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] ERROR com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - inAvailable channel closed; id:601172895 riak.address.org:8087
14:13:32.036 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] ERROR com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - inAvailable channel closed; id:-319701844 riak.address.org:8087
14:13:32.410 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] ERROR com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - inAvailable channel closed; id:-486690393 riak.address.org:8087
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the developers noticed the same thing, because [this bug](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/issues/628) was filed in June of last year, and and the message was reduced to INFO level in [this PR](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/pull/637) a month later.

If you're still seeing them as errors, update your java-riak-client to [v2.0.7](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/releases/tag/riak-client-2.0.7) or later.